# Checking measurability on open sets

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

This is exercise 5 of section 53 in Halmos' Measure theory.

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu^{*}$ an outer measure on the hereditary class of $\sigma$-bounded sets. Suppose $\mu^{*}(C)=\inf_{C \subset U, U \: \text{open}} \mu^{*}(U)<+\infty$ for every compact $C$.

Let $E$ be a $\sigma$-bounded set such that 
\begin{equation*}
\mu^{*}(U)=\mu^{*}(U\cap E) + \mu^{*}(U\cap E^{c})
\end{equation*}
for every open $U$. Is it true that $E$ is $\mu^{*}$-measurable ?

My guess is no, but I can't find a counter example.

Comment: Just a minor remark. The exercise 5 of section 53 in Halmos' Measure Theory says:  $\mu^{*}(C)=\inf_{C \subset U, U \: \text{open}} \mu^{*}(U)<+\infty$ for every compact $C$.

Comment: Indeed, I'll edit the post, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An example.

**Update:** Unfortunately, this is not a counterexample. The outer measure is not finite on compacts. The example can be modified (by removal of the point $\{(x^*,y^*)\}$) to ensure the finiteness on compacts but then the immeasurable set in question would not be $\sigma$-finite.

---

Consider two uncountable sets $X$, $Y$, both with the discrete topologies, and their one point compactifications: $X^* = X \cup \{x^*\}$ and $Y^* = Y \cup \{y^*\}$. Let also $A\subset X$ be such that both $A$ and $X\setminus A$ are uncountable.

Now,
$$
Z = X^* \times Y^*
$$
with the product topology is a compact Hausdorff space. Define an outer measure $\phi$ on $\mathcal P(Z)$:
$$
\phi(E) := \sum_{y\in Y^*} \mu_0(E_y) + \infty \cdot \chi_E(x^*,y^*),
$$
where $E_y := \{x\in X^*: (x,y) \in E\}$ and
$$
\mu_0(F) = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if $F$ is uncountable or } x^*\in F,\\
0, &\text{otherwise,} 
\end{cases}
\qquad \text{ for } F\subset X^*.
$$
The infinity term in the definition of $\phi$ (meaning that $\phi(\{(x^*,y^*)\}) = +\infty$) is to ensure outer regularity of the singleton $\{(x^*,y^*)\}$. Similarly, I choose $\mu_0$ so that $\mu_0(\{x^*\}) = 1$, which guarantees outer regularity of $\{x^*\}$. This will be seen later.

Clearly, the set $A\times \{y^*\}$ is not $\phi$-measureable because 
$$
1 = \phi(X\times \{y^*\}) < \phi(A\times \{y^*\}) + \phi((X\setminus A)\times \{y^*\}) = 2.
$$

However, for any open $U\subset Z$:
$$
\phi(U) \ge \phi(U\setminus A\times\{y^*\}) + \phi(U\cap A\times\{y^*\}).
$$
To see this, take $U$ such that $\phi (U\cap A\times\{y^*\})>0$, which means that $U\cap A\times\{y^*\}$ is uncountable. And if $(x,y^*) \in U$, then necessarily $\{x\}\times Y^* \cap U$ is cofinite. Then $U_y$ is uncountable for infinitely $y$'s, and consequently, $\phi(U) = +\infty$.

The only thing left is the outer regularity of $\phi$ on compacts. Take a compact $K$ of finite measure and consider compacts $K_y$ for $y\in Y^*$. I'll show that for any such compact, there exists an open set $U(y) \supset K_y\times \{y\}$ of the same measure.

Case $y\neq y^*$. If $K_y$ doesn't contain $x^*$, then it's already open (and finite). On the other hand, if $x^*\in K_y$ then $\mu_0(K_y) = 1$ and $K_y\times \{y\}$ can be approximated by $X^* \times \{y\}$.

Now, consider $K_{y^*}$. It doesn't contain $x^*$ because $K$ has finite measure. So, it must be finite (and of measure 0). An open set that approximates it is $K_{y^*} \times Y^*$, which also has zero measure.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you very much ! Just a minor remark: I don't think that $(\{x\}\times Y^{*})\cap U$ cofinite for every $x \in A$ implies that $E_{y}$ is uncountable for infinitely many $Y$. But it looks like it can be fixed if you give $Y$ more cardinality than $X$ (which doesn't change anything to the rest of the argument). Again, excellent answer.

Comment: Also the original problem wants an outer measure finite on all compacts (which doesn't work out here because of $\{x^*,y^*\}$). I'll try on my own to distort your answer to take care of it, but if it doesn't work it won't bother me much.

Comment: Thanks. You're right about the cardinality, I fixed this. And somehow I completely forgot about the finiteness on compacts. I hope you'll be able to fix it. But, on the other hand, it would be even more interesting if it occurs that, with all assumptions, the statement is actually true...

Comment: It looks like you really can't change your answer to take into account the finiteness condition. This exercise is really disturbing, it serves no purpose, and usually Halmos details counter-examples but not here...

Comment: It seems that you can get either the finiteness on compacts or sigma-finiteness of the immeasurable set, but not both. It wouldn't surprise me if the statement was true. Bogachev in Chap. 1.11-12 of his [book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540345138) (free for subscribed academic institutions I guess) considers a similar problem. I couldn't find the answer (I haven't read it all though) but you may find some clues there.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reference ! Btw I was wrong, even if $X$ and $Y$ have same cardinality your example still works (as long as they stay uncountable), it isn't so difficult to prove once you're convinced it is true.

Comment: @Sergio Thanks, updated the answer. I already got convinced that the cardinality condition was needed :) Anyway, I still feel a bit guilty about the undeserved bounty, so if, by any chance, I come across some answers, I'll get back to this.

Answer (score 0):

$E$ is  $\mu* measurable $

$\mu^{*}(U)=\mu^{*}(U\cap E) + \mu^{*}(U\cap E^{c})$ is also known as the Carathéodory's Criterion [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_criterion)
 Any set $E$ satisfying this criterion is measurable.
Remember $U$ is not even required to be measurable.

Comment: ofcourse any standard Real Analyis book has a proof of Carathéodory's Criterion implies measurability. for example see 'A radical approach to lebesgue's theory of integration' by David M. Bressoud.

Comment: The question is precisely to know whether $\mu^{*}(U)=\mu^{*}(U\cap E)+\mu^{*}(U\cap E')$ for *open* $U$ implies the same equality for *all* $U$, under the assumption that the topology is 'rich' enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question. The answer is no, it is not enough to check measurability on open sets.

Let $A,B,C$ be three sets that partition $[0,1]$, that have Lebesgue inner measure $0$ and Lebesgue outer measure $1$ (see section 16 in Halmos' book). Write $\lambda$ for Lebesgue measure.

Knowledge of $X\cap A$, with $X$ a Borel set, determines $X$ up to a $\lambda$-negligible set: if $(X\Delta Y)\cap A = \emptyset$ then $[0,1]-X\Delta Y$ covers $A$ so that $\lambda(X\Delta Y)=0$ because $A$ has outer measure $1$.

The sets of the form $(X\cap A) \cup (Y \cap B)\cup (Z\cap C)$ with Borel $X,Y,Z$ constitue a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$. For every $E\in \mathcal{A}$ define
\begin{align*}
\mu(E)&=\frac{\lambda(Y)}{2} \: \text{if} \: \lambda(X)=\lambda(Z)=0, \\
&= \frac{\lambda(X)+\lambda(Y)+\lambda(Z)}{3} \: \text{otherwise}.
\end{align*}.

It is easy to check that $\mu$ is monotone and countably subadditive, so it can be extended to an outer measure on $\mathcal{P}([0,1])$ by setting $\mu(E)=\inf_{F\in \mathcal{A}}\mu(A)$. Also for every compact set $C$
\begin{equation*}
\mu(C)=\lambda(C)=\inf_{C\subset U} \mu(U) \leqslant 1
\end{equation*}
and for every open set $U$
\begin{equation*}
\mu(U)=\mu(U\cap A) + \mu(U \cap A').
\end{equation*}
Yet
\begin{equation*}
2/3=\mu(A\cup B) < \mu(A) + \mu(B) = 5/6
\end{equation*}
so that $A$ is not measurable.